# c++ overloading operator<< and operator>>

Tags: c++

```
class Book
{ 
     string title;
     int category;
 public:
    Book(const string& abook, int num);
    string getTitle() const;
    int getCategory() const;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Book& abook);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Book& abook);
 };

class Reader  // base class
{
private:
    string reader_name;
    vector<Book> bookLists;
public:
   string showname() const;
   void add(const Book& abook);    // organize book list
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Reader& read_name);
   friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Reader& read_name);
};

 class fantasyReader : public Reader {  };
 class horrorReader : public Reader { };
 class scienceReader : public Reader { } ;
class mysteryReader : public Reader { };
```

I have two given text files.
1) Reader.txt <--- contains reader's name and category
For ex.
David  <- reader's name
0      <- david is Fantasy reader

2) Book.txt <---- contains Book's title and category

For ex
Riddick <- Book's title 
0      <- Book's category is fantasy

In the main function, array of pointers to Reader's obj are pointing each dervied class;

```
 ex

Reader *obj[10];
int pos =0;
obj[pos++] = new fantasyReader();
```

The main goal is to organize book's list and put into a appropriate category and appropriate reader
 and write them into a new text file.
ex.
-David-
Riddick

-John-
The Crow

MY QUESTION
I'm not sure what should be inside of operator<< and operator>>
for class Book and class Reader

Comment: You should try to explain the problem in greater detail, more than the proposed solution. For example, the creation or the readers in `main` looks suspicious, how are books related to readers if there are more than one reader for a given type of book? Another thing that is suspicious is that the type of reader is encoded in the type of the object, but the derived types do not add anything to the base class... empty subclasses are not that common.

Answer (score 6):

***What should you put inside the overloaded << and >> operators?***
Well, You can actually put anything inside the overloaded `<<` and `>>` operator. They will just be simple function calls whenever a appropriate opportunity presents.
For eg:

```
Book obj;
cout<< obj;  //Calls your overloaded << operator
```

As a general principle while overloading operators you should follow ***Principle of Least Astonishment***, which means your code should be doing something similar what the operator does for a intrinsic data type. In the above example I would expect my `<<` operator to display the contents of my `Book` class, in that case I would overload it as follows:

```
// Display title and category 
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Book& abook);
{
    os << abook.title << "\n";
    os << abook.category<< "\n";

    return os; // must return ostream object
}
```

I need to return a stream object since it allows for the `chaining` ex:

```
Book obj1,obj2,obj3;
cout<<obj1<<obj2<<obj3;
```

Similarly, for `>>` Extraction operator I would expect the operator to get the data from user.
For ex:

```
Book obj;
cin>>obj; //Calls your overloaded >> operator
```

I would overload the `>>` operator as follows:

```
//Get the Book Title & Category from User
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Book& abook)
{
    cout << "Enter Book Title: ";
    is >> abook.title ;
    cout << "Enter Book Category: ";
    is >> abook.category;

    return is;  //Must return stream object
}
```

***So, the bottomline is You can put any functionality inside `>>` and `<<` operators but don't forget the Principle of Least Astonishment!***

Comment: +1, good answer.  For these operators I always follow the rule of thumb that, `<<` is for putting things in to other things and `>>` is for taking things out :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: You can use the analogy hidden in names, >> (Extraction operator, Extracts something from the Stream) <<(Insertion operator, Inserts something to the Stream), The words Extraction & Insertion are w.r.t the Streams.